# Android create a Library for support and non-support without duplicating code

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on a library in android that attempts to ease navigation using `Fragments`. I am having some trouble with how I can maintain the code with some upcoming changes that I want to make.

Currently I using the support library only (since this can be used in past and current version of android), but i would like to offer (and have been asked if I could offer) a non support version of the library. On top of this my has 2 version (one `Fragment` and the other `ListFragment`) so that I can support both `Fragment` types. I am currently duplicating code between `Fragment` and `ListFragment` as there is no way to at runtime decide which it extends from. To ensure I always implement the methods on both classes they both implement `INavigationFragment` so that there is no human error in missing a class, plus this let's me pass around my fragments without worrying if they are a `ListFragment` or a `Fragment`.

My question is if anyone knows of a way that I can support both `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` without having to duplicate my code all over the place? I have made the core of my manager clean that it should be able to easily use the proper non-support/support fragment but I can't seem to think of an easy way to do it for the fragments themselves.

Please see here to see how I'm currently handling the support library. https://github.com/DMCApps/NavigationFragment/tree/master/navigation-fragment/src/main/java/com/dmcapps/navigationfragment

I have a few thoughts but I'm not sure if there is another way that anyone can help me out with.

My thoughts (1 being what I think is best to keep down the amount of code I have to write):

1. Create an `Annotation Processor` for my support `NavigationFragment` which then creates the `NavigationListFragment` and the non-support fragments, by changing the imports and extends appropriately.
2. Scrap the `NavigationListFragment` and make the user implement there own List gathering in onCreateView. (I hate to do this but it'll make managing the code easier).

I guess I only have 2 ways that I can remember.

Thanks,
DMCApps

Comment: Pull as much logic out of the fragment as possible into a separate controller-style class. Have each of your four fragment implementations delegate relevant callbacks to an instance of the controller. You then just wind up duplicating those tiny callbacks, as most of your actual business logic is in the controller class. The annotation processor sounds cool but strikes me as a yak-shaving exercise, unless you are specifically looking to learn how to use JavaPoet and kin to generate Java code at compile time.

Comment: @CommonWare Thanks for the suggestion, I have already done it this way. All the Fragments call back to a main "Manager" but anytime I want to do something new in the fragments I add it to the Manager but then have to add it to all 4 fragments (more annoyance than unmanageable I guess). I should have explained that there is not much logic in the fragments themselves. They are more just helper methods in the Fragments so you don't have to call `getNavigationManager().[ActionToPerform]` it simplifies it to just `[ActionToPerform]`

Comment: "more annoyance than unmanageable I guess" -- it's the sort of thing that for this one case would not be worth an annotation processor IMHO. Where an annotation processor would make more sense is if you wanted to dump some/all of your built-in fragments and have the developer using your library use an annotation to add the calls to your manager.

Comment: What would be interesting (but AFAIK does not exist) is a general-purpose forwarding annotation processor framework ("if the user adds `@Foo` to a subclass of `Bar`, forward this list of methods along to another object"). But that's a whole 'nuther library, and the yak hair starts to pile up.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm guessing your second comment is referencing something like Objective-c's method swizzling (http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/)? I'm not sure I understand where that would make my life easier. I still need all the fragments for the user to extend from to ensure that they have the proper Fragment (List or not, support or not) to extend from when making their Fragments.

Comment: "I'm guessing your second comment is referencing something like Objective-c's method swizzling" -- since I don't know Objective-C, no methods were swizzled in the creation of my previous comments. :-) I don't know enough about your scenario to know whether an annotation processor for the users of your library would be practical or not. I was merely citing that possibility as a scenario that might start to justify the mental overhead of writing an annotation processor.

Comment: @CommonsWare alright well I appreciate the discussion. I'll have to keep searching and maybe look deeper into the annotation processor to see if it's worth it. I was looking at it and it definitely seems complex so I'll have to way the pros and cons of doing it that way vs how it is currently working and get back to this issue when I figure more out.